# base.html isn't being picked up by template unless I rename it to something else

Tags: python, django

When running my django app in production the base.html is being correctly picked up by the templates that have "{% extends "base.html" %}" - but on my local machine the page renders without it.

If I change the name of base.html to anything else (literally any valid file name) then it works.

Comment: check if you have another file with name `base.html` in your all template directories.

Comment: I see one double quote missing. `{% extends "base.html %}` :P

Comment: Thanks Rohan. I've taken a look and there aren't any other base.html files anywhere in the project. What I did find however, is that the template_dir was pointing to a non existent directory. Once I change it to the correct directory it picks up base.html. What I don't understand is why changing the name of base.html to another.html also fixes the problem. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Thanks Bibhas, purely a typo in the question